# BitTorrent tracker announce problem

Tags: c#, bittorrent

I've been throwing a little bit of spare time at writing a BitTorrent client, mostly out of curiosity but partly out of a desire to improve my c# skills.

I've been using [the theory wiki](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) as my guide.  I've built up a library of classes for handling BEncoding, which I'm quite confident in; basically because the sanity check is to regenerate the original .torrent file from my internal representation immediately after parsing, then hash and compare.

The next stage is to get tracker announces working.  Here I hit a stumbling block, because trackers reject my requests without terribly useful error messages.

Take, for instance, the [latest stack overflow database dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/so-export-2009-07.7z.torrent).  My code generates the following announce URI:

```
http://208.106.250.207:8192/announce?info_hash=-%CA8%C1%C9rDb%ADL%ED%B4%2A%15i%80Z%B8%F%C&peer_id=01234567890123456789&port=6881&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=0&compact=0&no_peer_id=0&event=started
```

The tracker's response to my code:

```
d14:failure reason32:invalid info hash and/or peer ide
```

The tracker's response to that string dropped into Chrome's address bar:

```
d8:completei2e11:external ip13:168.7.249.11110:incompletei0e8:intervali600e5:peerslee
```

The peer_id is (valid) garbage, but changing it to something sensible (impersonating a widely used client) doesn't change anything.

Like I said, I'm pretty sure I'm pulling the info dictionary out properly and hashing (SHA1) like I should, and the peer id is well formed.

My guess is I'm doing some minor thing stupidly wrong, and would appreciate any help in spotting what it is exactly.

Its kind of hard to guess what code would be pertinent (and there's far to much to just post).  However, I'll try and post anything asked for.

*EDIT*
I wasn't hex encoding the info_hash, which sort of helps.

This is the code that takes the generates URI and try's to fetch a response:

```
//uri is the above
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MonoTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoTorrent) is a BitTorrent implementation that comes with Mono.
In the [HTTPTracker class](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/bitsharp/src/MonoTorrent/MonoTorrent.Client/Tracker/HTTPTracker.cs?view=markup) there is a `CreateAnnounceString` method.
Maybe you can compare your implementation with how that method is doing it?
(You probably need to hunt down where the `AnnounceParameters` instance is created.)

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you hashing? You should only hash the `info` section, not the whole torrent file... So basically, decode the file, reencode the `info` section, hash that.

ie. For the torrent posted, all you should be hashing is:

```
d6:lengthi241671490e4:name20:so-export-2009-07.7z12:piece lengthi262144e6:pieces18440:<lots of binary data>e
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your problem, but it may help for testing.

There are open-source PHP-based torrent trackers out there.  They are incredibly inefficient (I know, I wrote a caching mechanism for one back in the day), but you could set up your own local tracker and modify the PHP code to help debug your client as it communicates with the tracker.  Having a local client-server setup would make troubleshooting a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is a error in the URL %-encoding of the info_hash. The leading zeros in the two last bytes of the info_hash has been removed.

```
It is:     info_hash=-%CA8%C1%C9rDb%ADL%ED%B4%2A%15i%80Z%B8%F%C
Should be: info_hash=-%CA8%C1%C9rDb%ADL%ED%B4%2A%15i%80Z%B8%0F%0C
```

When the announce string is dropped into Chrome's address bar it's probably auto-corrected by the browser.