# HttpWebRequest truncating URL with non-english symbols in it

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm creating HttpWebRequest with a dynamic URL that can sometimes contain Russian symbols. 
And sometimes I'm encounter an issue I not sure how to deal with: While encoding to URL each of RU characters has been converted into URL character-entity equivalents (%20...). Apparently after such conversion URL is becoming too long so HttpWebRequest truncating few last characters so instead of proper HTTP result I'm getting 404 error.

Is there any way to bypass this limitation?

My URL looks like this:

```
http:\\1.1.1.1\some?page=2&var=тестовое значение строки (this part can be very long)
```

I'm sending this as a GET since web-app I'm working with is expecting GET request at this point.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get around URL encoding to ASCII nor the length limit in a Request

Comment: If you are sending that much data, you really should try to use a POST request and pass your data that way instead of via a URL parameter in a GET request. This is typically the recommended method and if there is logging enabled on the web server, your log files will not get overwhelmed with extraneous details.

Comment: This other thread might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587857/httpwebrequest-long-uri-workaround

Answer (score 0):

The only answer to this is you have to send it in any other way as there is a limit for the length of a query string.

The error 404 or "HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long." you'll get only because of the length of the query string as the data you are sending is longer than the limit.

refer this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1139751.aspx